# How to select ticks at n-positions in a log plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, sometime the major-ticks are too close to each other in a `loglog` plot. Instead of setting them manually, can one use something similar to `MaxNLocator` to put ticks at n-locations in a log scale?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p

x=np.logspace(1,20,10)

fig=p.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.loglog(x,x,'o')
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.loglog(x,x,'o')
fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each axis you could set a [LogLocator](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator):

```
from matplotlib import ticker
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(base = 1000.0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the newest version of matplotlib (1.2.0), to get something more similar to `MaxNLocator`
you could also use @unutbu 's solution with

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(numticks=6))
```